# Can ng-repeat displays data based on a rule? *filter*

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two selects (multi-select /picklist).

I need to display clients on both sides, but:

- The picklist on left, should display only clients that have this field 'consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente' as true in 'cliente' table.
- The picklist on right, should display only clients that have this field 'consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente' as false in 'cliente' table.

How can I do this?

Here goes my html:

```
   <div class="form group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
         <select id="select1" name="select1" multiple="multiple">
             <option ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}" ng-click="atribuirUm($index, c)">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>                            
         </select>
         <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
         <select ng-model="listaEmpresas" id="select2" name="select2" multiple="multiple">
             <option selected="selected" ng-repeat="c2 in clientes2" value="{{c2.idCliente}}" ng-click="limparUm($index, c2)">{{c2.razaoSocial}}</option>                              
         </select>                               
   </div>
```

Comment: ng-show / ng-hide is another option if you don't mind getting the content to the browser for later display

Comment: `ng-repeat="c in clients | filter:{consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente: true}"` you can construct somthing like that

Comment: Why are you not posting that as an answer @maurycy  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pipe `|` to pass data to filters

```
ng-repeat="c in clients | filter:{consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente: true}"
```

You can actually pipe as many build in and custom filters as you want i.e

```
ng-repeat="c in clients | filter:{consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente: true} | limitTo:4 | json"
```

Filters documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter

Comment: Maurycy, please, if I am receiving an object instead of a collection, how can I do? Because I get this: "Error: filter:notarray Not an array"